# Facebook graphi API get user groups access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a long term access token for a group I am an administrator in. A few months ago I ran this and was able to get the access token for the group and then get a long term access token. That token has now expired and I am trying to get a new long-term access token, but when I run this:

```
$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts")
```

I get all the account information showing my pages but no info on my groups, if I run this:

```
$result = $facebook->api("/me/groups")
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Does anyone know if anything has changed with graph API in last few months? or have any advise for me please?

Comment: Did you grant `user_groups` permission?

Comment: hi, thank you very much that gave me more info, but not the access token for the page, the response I got is like this:[4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => [Group name]
                    [administrator] => 1
                    [bookmark_order] => 1
                    [id] => [group id]
                )      , do you know how do I get the access token?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.